# C# WebPages : manage Exit events or quit with no user action server side

Tags: c#, idisposable, exit, onunload, quit

What is the better solution to manage Exit or Quit events when user exit to other pages with no action?. This event need to be raised only **one time** and be usefull to delete all temporary files or datas not stored after the abandon of this page. Is a perfect to use as cleaning method server side. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The web is stateless so there shouldn't really be anything to clean up.  However, sometimes you may want to kill the session when the user tries to close browser.  I guess you could catch that event and then call the server (using AJAX) before closing the window:

[How to capture the browser window close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event)

Not 100% reliable though IMHO!