# How do I automatically delete an Excel file after creating it on a server and returning it to the user?

Tags: .net, excel, file, model-view-controller, delete-file

I am creating an Excel file on a web server, using OleDb to connect the the physical (well as physical as it can be) file and appending records. I am then returning a **FilePathResult** to the user via MVC, and would like to delete the physical file afterwards due to data protection concerns over the appended records.

I have tried using a **File.Delete** in a **Finally** clause but I get a File Not Found error which must mean the file has gone when MVC is trying to send the file to the user.

I thought about creating the File as a MemoryStream but I think OleDb needs a physical file to connect to so this isn't an option.

Any suggestions on how to delete the file after returning it in one operation?

**Edit**

As requested this is what I'm working from, though I'm not sure how it helps :)

```
    Public Function ExportAllOutputs() As FilePathResult

        ' Create Export File Name
        Dim ExportFilename As String = Replace(Me.Name, " ", "_") & "_Outputs.xls"

        Try

            ' Create Export File
            CreateExportFile(ExportFilename)

            ' Populate Export File
            For Each OutputType As OutputTypeEnum In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(OutputTypeEnum))
                ExportHelper.AppendOutputs(ExportFilepath & ExportFilename, Me.GetOutputs(OutputType), Me.ProgrammeID)
            Next

            ' Return Export File
            Return ReturnExportFile(ExportFilename)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally
            'If IO.File.Exists(ExportFilepath & ExportFilename) Then IO.File.Delete(ExportFilepath & ExportFilename)
        End Try

    End Function
```

Comment: You should be aware that OleDb is not supported on 64 bit machines, so you should find another solution for future proofing your code.

Comment: Could you post some code for this?

Comment: I was NOT aware that OleDb is not 64bit - I will have to make a note of that but it isn't an issue at the moment, cheers Cine, also I have added the function where I think a solution would go but not sure it really helps.

Comment: Also I think I may end up doing as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709958/c-on-quit-webpage-delete-files-and-folders-on-server-with-no-user-action if I don't get any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat hacky, but you could do as below:

1. read the file into a byte array in memory using File.ReadAllBytes(),
2. delete the file,
3. form a memory stream around the byte array
4. get MVC to return data via the stream using FileStreamResult.

Clearly, if the files are large then you may get memory pressures.

Comment: Hi Neil, that makes perfect sense - create the real file using ADO - THEN read it into a Memory Stream - then delete it - so simple :) Cheers for that